# show/hide multiple divs based on dropdown box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combobox

I have a Combobox which has the values 1,2,3 and 4 respectively.
I also have 4 divs named div1, div2, div3 and div4 respectively.

I want a javascript with the following conditions:
- when selected value 1 from the combobox, it should display div1
- when selected value 2 from the combobox, it should display div1 and div2
- when selected value 3 from the combobox, it should display div1, div2 and div3
- when selected value 4 from the combobox, it should display div1, div2, div3 and div4
- again if clicked on value 2 from the combobox, it should automatically hide div3 and div4 and should only show div1 and div2

I found some fiddles on stackoverflow, but it does not do what I need.

I tried hard to do that but in the end I end up toggling a single div.

Comment: please share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: @abtpst http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/420/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This would let you show the divs in the sequential order.

```
$('div').hide();
$('select').click(function()
{ 
    var targetDiv = $("#div" + $(this).val());
    var prevDiv = $($("#div" + $(this).val())).prev('div');
    if($(this).val() == "1" || prevDiv.is(":visible") )
      $("#div" + $(this).val()).show();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/3/

UPDATE :

In order to show items with combo select value til the 1st div, just perform a for loop in reverse order.

```
$('div').hide();
$('select').click(function()
{ 
    $('div').hide(); // remove this if you don't want to hide all of them 
    for(var i = $(this).val() ; i >= 1 ; i--)
        $("#div" + i).show();      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/6/

Comment: in your example, when I click on 4, it shows div1,div2,div3 and div4. Again if I click 2 then all the divs should hide and should only show me div1 and div2. In your example, all the 4 divs stay even if I click on 2

Comment: Updated the solution just now. Try the new fiddle.

Comment: it does not work the way I described. try your example by clicking backwards from 4 to 1

Comment: what you need is even simpler. Check out the UPDATE. The basic idea is to perform for loop but in reverse order. This would eradicate the need of switch or if-else statement completely.

Comment: Thanks Man. The solution worked like a charm. I didn't knew that it could be done without a if-else statement. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```js
$(document).on('change','#combobox',function(){
    var selected = $("#combobox option:selected");
    if ($("#div" + selected.val()).length > 0) {
     $("#div" + selected.val()).prevAll().show();
        $("#div" + selected.val()).nextAll().hide();
        $("#div" + selected.val()).show();
 }
    else {
        $('.container > div').show();
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    height: 30px;
}
#div1 {
    background-color:green;
}

#div2 {
    background-color:orange;
}

#div3 {
    background-color:blue;
}

#div4 {
    background-color:red;
}

#div5 {
    background-color:#c23abc;
}

#div6 {
    background-color:#c2da2c;
}

#div7 {
    background-color:#e26ab1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="combobox" name="select">
  <option value="all">Show all</option> 
  <option value="1">Show till div 1</option> 
  <option value="2">Show till div 2</option>
  <option value="3">Show till div 3</option>
  <option value="4">Show till div 4</option>
  <option value="5">Show till div 5</option>
  <option value="6">Show till div 6</option>
  <option value="7">Show till div 7</option>
    
</select>
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
    <div id="div5"></div>
    <div id="div6"></div>
    <div id="div7"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - radio buttons can help control state, and you can display those divs accordingly with them. Here's a good article on the radio button hack http://alistapart.com/article/radio-controlled-web-design

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the [on change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
$(document).on('change','#combobox',function(){
    var selected = $("#combobox option:selected").val;
    switch(selected){
        case '1': /* do something */ break;
        case '2': /* do something */ break;
        case '3': /* do something */ break;
        default: break;
    }
})
```

Comment: You could use if statements instead of a switch, but a switch seemed faster to type. XD